# Getting Python Entry Point Not Found when trying to launch Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Below is a screenshot of the Entry Point error I get when I try to launch Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Prompt. I am using conda 4.7.12 with Python 3.7.4 on Windows 7. Interestingly enough the Jupyter Notebook will still launch and I can use it. I also get the following error message in the Anaconda prompt as soon as I run the command.

```
jupyter notebook

ECHO "WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your c
ompiler may not work"
 GOTO End
)
"WARNING: Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - your compil
er may not work"
The system cannot find the batch label specified - End
```

[image: Entry Point Error when trying to launch Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Prompt]

Answer (score 3):

I also had the exactly same problem after creating new environment and installing python and tensorflow in that particular environment.

My problem got resolved by switching back to base environment
then upgrading `conda` and `anaconda` :-

```
conda upgrade conda 
conda upgrade anaconda
```

Now switch back to my concerned environment --- NO ERROR

Answer (score 0):

since i can't comment yet i found this link [github](https://github.com/flatironinstitute/CaImAn/issues/418)
and they suggest the following:
execute:

`conda install -n caiman vs2017_win-64`